# Getting null token on first time when the app is downloaded on IOS with Ionic 3

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications

When I run my app directly by USB, I get the token normally, but I've uploaded the app to testFlight and at the first time that I run the app on the device, I get the token null by Firebase servers. If I close the app and open it again, the token is generated and the push notifications work correctly.

I'm using the plugin: Cordova-plugin-firebase

Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 15 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/bruno/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

I've tried:
- Download the app -> open it -> close it -> open it again and get the token

I've put the token request on app.components.ts, to get it when the app opens.

```
solicitarToken(){
    this.firebase.grantPermission();
    this.firebase.getToken()
    .then(token => {
      Settings.push_token = token;
      this.iniciarListenerDeNotificacoes();
      return token;
    }) 
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error getting token', error);
      return null;      
    });


  }
```

This request is placed at the end of the constructor.

I didn't get any error messages, only the null token. I've read that sometimes Firebase needs time to generate the token. I thought in wait some milliseconds, but I need an assertive solution because the apple analyses app has a delay of about 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Please use function this.platform.ready .

Comment: I recommend against answers in the shape of a rethoric question. They risk being mistaken for clarification questions, which should of course be avoided as long as the commenting privilege is not yet reached. So please, [edit] this into an obvious answer, or delete it and wait for your commenting privilege to ask this for clarification purposes.

Comment: Good. Now, could you add some explanation? It would be nice to understand how this works and why it solves the problem.